# Fastest way to read binary into int[] in java?

Tags: java, binary

In java, what is the fastest way to read a huge binary file into `int[]`. I saw this solution

[Fastest way to read huge number of int from binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022053/fastest-way-to-read-huge-number-of-int-from-binary-file)

But there is two solutions, and I don't know which is better. Also they seem to give a fixed maximum size for the int[], but how can I do it with a variable size? Like how can I set it to fit the amount of data in the binary exactly. Is there a way to know how many ints are there in the file?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try both and see for yourself?

Comment: What about my second question?

Comment: Well if you know how big the file is, and y you know how many bytes are in an int, you can calculate how many ints are in the file.

Comment: How do you do the calculation? Can you show example?

Comment: Assuming you're not using a variable length encoding, there are 4 bytes per int. So, the number of ints is just bytesInTheFile / 4.

Comment: new File(path).length() / 4?

Answer (score 0):

You could have some variables to calculate the time in both solutions, then compare the two.

```
while (bytesRead != -1) {
  double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   while(doingstuff){}
  double timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
}
```

As for the array, you could use a arraylist which is expandable.

```
ArrayList<int> binary = new ArrayList<int>();
binary.add(stuff);
```

Comment: System.nanoTime() is better for micro benchmarking.

Comment: Also this should be a comment and not an answer.